# Asus Router RT- N12 D1 not connecting with pppoe

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have just bought a new Asus RT-N12 D1 router and trying to configure it. My ISP support PPPOE connection and i have a user name and password. when i use the same use username and password to connect directly to my laptop(without router), every thing works fine, but when i tried to configure router and use same username and password its not connecting and saying "either username or password are incorrect". did't understand why username and password is not working on router while same username and password is working fine when i directly connect through laptop. is there any thing extra i need to configure on router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys finally i solved the issue. The MAC address was creating a issue. The ISP have registered my laptops MAC address and it was allowing the internet access on only my laptop. as router have different MAC address it was treated as another machine and denying connection. To solve this problem i have to clone my laptop's MAC address on router. This option is available on almost every new router. [You can see the detail here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100424231434AALh7zd)